# Can't construct instance of ``(although at least one Creator exists): no Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (10)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

When applying a post request via postman:

I got such an error/response:

Any Ideas?

[image]

> 2022-12-11 15:43:43.355  WARN 20344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of
> `HogeschoolLeiden.IPRWCApp.product.ProductDto` (although at least one
> Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to
> deserialize from Number value (10); nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> construct instance of `HogeschoolLeiden.IPRWCApp.product.ProductDto`
> (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument
> constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (10)
> at [Source:
> (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 2,
> column: 16] (through reference chain:
> HogeschoolLeiden.IPRWCApp.orderItem.OrderItemDto["product"])]

Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_name", columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "product_photo", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String productPhoto;

    @Column(name = "product_prise", columnDefinition = "INT", nullable = false)
    private int productPrise;

    @Column(name = "product_description", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String productDescription;
}
```

ProductDto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductDto {

    private Long productId;
    private String productName;
    private String productPhoto;
    private int productPrise;
    private String productDescription;
}
```

OrderItem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_ITEM")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OrderItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Product.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "quantity", nullable = false)
    private int quantity;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private Order orderCart;
}
```

OrderItemDto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderItemDto {
    private Long id;
    private ProductDto product;
    private int quantity;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
    private Order orderCart;
}
```

OrderItemService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class OrderItemService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepo productRepo;
    @Autowired
    private OrderItemRepo orderItemRepo;
    @Autowired
    private OrderItemMapper orderItemMapper;

    public OrderItemDto addProductToCart(OrderItemDto orderItemDto) {
        OrderItem orderItem = orderItemMapper.toOrderItem(orderItemDto);
//        Product producty = productRepo.findProductById(orderItemDto.getProduct().getProductId());
//        OrderItem orderItem = OrderItem.builder()
//                .product(producty)
//                .quantity(orderItemDto.getQuantity())
//                .appUser(orderItemDto.getAppUser())
//                .build();
        log.info("Saving new Order-Item: {} to the database.", orderItem.getProduct().getId());
        if (orderItem.getProduct().getId() != null) {
            orderItemRepo.save(orderItem);
            return orderItemMapper.toDTO(orderItem);
        }
        throw new ResponseStatusException(
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Order-Item with order-id: " + orderItem.getId() + " doesn't exist between products."
        );
    }

    public List<OrderItemDto> getAllOrderItemsDto() {
        List<OrderItem> orderItemList = orderItemRepo.findAll();
        log.info(orderItemList.toString());
        return orderItemMapper.toDTOs(orderItemList);
    }

    public OrderItemDto getOrderItemDto(Long id) {
        OrderItem orderItem = getOrderItem(id);
        return orderItemMapper.toDTO(orderItem);
    }

    private OrderItem getOrderItem(Long id) {
        return orderItemRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->
                new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        );
    }

    public void deleteOrderItem(Long id){
        if (!orderItemRepo.existsById(id)) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "No OrderItem found with id: " + id);
        }
        orderItemRepo.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is thrown because the number 10 can't be deserialized to a `ProductDto` object.

Change request body to:

```json
{
  "product": {
    "productId": 10
  },
  "quantity": 3
}
```